# Go template name

Tags: go, go-templates

In the `html/template` (and `text/template`) packages, [`template.New`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#New) has the following signature:

```
func New(name string) *Template
```

What exactly is the `name` used for? I've scanned the docs (and a bit of source), but to no avail. I just instantiate all of my templates with an empty string and it doesn't seem to make a difference. Why should I bother with a name?

Even for naming templates, the two seem equivalent:

```
template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{ define "body" }}Body{{ end }}`))
template.Must(template.New("body").Parse(`Body`))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/wKzCHdLf2S

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The name of the template–unsurprisingly–is to *name* the template.

What is it good for? As long as you don't want to *refer* to the template, it doesn't really matter. But if you want to *refer* to it, then yes, you refer to it by its *name*.

When would you want to refer to it? When you want to include a template in another e.g. using the `{{template}}` action, or when you want to execute a specific template using [`Template.ExecuteTemplate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.ExecuteTemplate).

So far so good, but there's still a missing key point. This is not unambiguous / trivial: a [`template.Template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template) value is *"the representation of a parsed template"*. But the wording here is a little "imperfect". A `template.Template` value may be (and usually is) *a collection of multiple, associated templates*. `template.Template` has an unexported field:

```
tmpl   map[string]*Template // Map from name to defined templates.
```

This `tmpl` field holds all other associated templates, templates that are visible to the template, and which can be referred to–yes–by their *names*.

When you parse *multiple* templates at once, using [`Template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#ParseFiles) or [`Template.ParseGlob()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#ParseGlob), then the templates will be named by the file names, and they will be associated automatically (the above mentioned functions return a single `template.Template` value, which holds all the parsed templates, associated). Doc of `Template.ParseFiles()` is clear on this:

> ParseFiles creates a new Template and parses the template definitions from the named files. The returned template's name will have the base name and parsed contents of the first file. [...]
>
> When parsing multiple files with the same name in different directories, the last one mentioned will be the one that results. For instance, ParseFiles("a/foo", "b/foo") stores "b/foo" as the template named "foo", while "a/foo" is unavailable.

The template name can come from multiple *places*:

- it can come from the file name (as seen above)
- it can be specified explicitly (if defined using the `{{define "somename"}}` or `{{block "somename"}}` actions),
- **or it may be defined as an argument passed to [`template.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#New) (function) or [`Template.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.New) (method)**.

Let's see some examples:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("one").Parse(t1src))
    template.Must(t.New("other").Parse(t2src))

    // error checks omitted for brevity
    // Executes default, "one":
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)

    // Executes explicit, "one":
    t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "one", nil)

    // Executes explicit, "other":
    t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "other", nil)
}

const t1src = `I'm some template.
`
const t2src = `I'm some OTHER template.
`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZwuQ4C4kwV)):

```
I'm some template.
I'm some template.
I'm some OTHER template.
```

If you now go ahead, and change the first 2 lines to this:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("one").Parse(t1src))
t = template.Must(t.New("other").Parse(t2src))
```

Then what happens here is that we assigned a new `template.Template` value to `t`, which was the result of parsing `t2src`, so that will be the default, but still both templates can be "reached" from it as they are associated. The output changes to this (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Brc3iWcd7r)):

```
I'm some OTHER template.
I'm some template.
I'm some OTHER template.
```

Calling `template.New()` (function) creates a new template, associated to none. When calling `Template.New()` (method), the returned template will be associated with (all) the template(s) the method is called on.

Now let's see some examples regarding "embedded" templates.

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("one").Parse(t1src))
    template.Must(t.New("other").Parse(t2src))
    template.Must(t.New("third").Parse(t3src))

    t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
    t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "one", nil)
    t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "other", nil)
    t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "embedded", nil)
    t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "third", nil)
}

const t1src = `I'm some template. {{block "embedded" .}}I'm embedded in "one".
{{end}}`
const t2src = `I'm some OTHER template.
`
const t3src = `I'm the 3rd, including everything from "one": {{template "one"}}
`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7Hms2Z7joy)):

```
I'm some template. I'm embedded in "one".
I'm some template. I'm embedded in "one".
I'm some OTHER template.
I'm embedded in "one".
I'm the 3rd, including everything from "one": I'm some template. I'm embedded in "one".
```

It should be obvious now what the role of the template name is, and where it comes from.

Answer (score 6):

It is used to render associated templates.

For instance:

```
tmpl := template.Must(template.New("body").Parse(`
    {{ define "body" }}
       Body
    {{ end }}
    `))

tmpl = template.Must(tmpl.New("base").Parse(`
     Start of base template

     {{ template "body" }}

     End of base template
    `))

tmpl = template.Must(tmpl.New("baz").Parse(`
     Start of baz template

     {{ template "body" }}

     End of baz template
    `))

tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "base", nil)
tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "baz", nil)
```

[Play Example](https://play.golang.org/p/LLrbtoKnNB)

Output:

```
     Start of base template


       Body


     End of base template

     Start of baz template


       Body


     End of baz template
```

`tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "base", nil)` will render the template using the "base" template

`tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "baz", nil)` will render the template using the "baz" template

Comment: Except that if I change that first line to `template.New("")` then it works just as well. https://play.golang.org/p/zQoGalIxFq

But I think you're on to something. `ExecuteTemplate` doesn't seem to work without naming the "base" template.

Comment: Here's the same example, but with empty strings for all the template names. https://play.golang.org/p/0NdJ1j_ype It looks like `{{ define "name" }}` works as an alternative to naming the template in the `New` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the name, you can just use the `new` builtin with
[template.Template](//pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template):

```
package main

import (
   "os"
   "text/template"
)

func main() {
   t, err := new(template.Template).Parse("hello {{.}}\n")
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   t.Execute(os.Stdout, "world")
}
```