# How to parse multiple strings into a template with Go?

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

Is there a simple way like `template.ParseFiles("base.html", "home.html")` but for strings to build a template from a set of strings?

I have a base template and a list of pages templates (all as strings) that I want to build on top of base template.

I figured out how to merge them, but I my solution is quite verbose and doesn't look elegant enough, even though working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may create a new, empty template using [`template.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#New) *function*. Then you may use the [`Template.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.New) *method* to create a new, empty, *associated* template. And you may parse "into" this using the [`Template.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Parse) method.

Here's how it could look like:

```
func parseTemplates(templs ...string) (t *template.Template, err error) {
    t = template.New("_all")

    for i, templ := range templs {
        if _, err = t.New(fmt.Sprint("_", i)).Parse(templ); err != nil {
            return
        }
    }

    return
}
```

Testing it:

```
t, err := parseTemplates(
    `{{define "one"}}I'm #1.{{end}}`,
    `{{define "two"}}I'm #2, including #1: {{template "one" .}}{{end}}`,
)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

if err = t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "two", nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8GYU1kh6CK)):

```
I'm #2, including #1: I'm #1.
```

Also see related question: [Go template name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176355/go-template-name/41187671#41187671)

### Note

While we could call the [`Template.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Parse) method on a single template multiple times, and it would parse multiple *named* templates properly, it is still advisable to acquire a new [`template.Template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template) for each by calling `Template.New()`. Because if the template texts have content *outside* of named templates, they will be overwritten and only the last would be retained. For example: `abc {{define "one"}}no 1{{end}}`. The static text `"abc"` would be lost by a subsequent `Template.Parse()` call.

This is also noted in the doc of `Template.Parse()`:

> (In multiple calls to Parse with the same receiver template, only one call can contain text other than space, comments, and template definitions.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
for _, templ := range ListOfPagesTemplates{
    YourBaseTemplate.Parse(templ)
}
```

err check absent for simplicity of reading

Comment: While this may be used to parse multiple _named_ templates, without acquiring a new `template.Template` for each by calling `Template.New()`, if the template texts have content _outside_ of named templates, they will be overwritten and only the last will be retained. Example: `abc {{define "one"}}no 1{{end}}`. The static text `"abc"` would be lost by a subsequent `Parse()`. See my answer for details.

Comment: @icza Yes, your answer is more exact and detailed for sure. I only show the way it can be done.