# Telling Golang which template to execute first

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I have a folder with different templates in golang. The main template is *main.html* and there is also a *footer.html* and *header.html*. Footer and Header are loaded with

```
{{template "footer.html" .}}
```

in *main.html*.

I am using this to parse the files

```
templates, _ := template.ParseGlob("Templates/" + template_name + "/*.html")
```

because there are other directories with different file names used aswell. So I don't want to use *parseFiles*.

However, the template that is displayed is always the first one in alphabetical order, e.g. *footer.html*. If I rename *main.html* to *a.html* the template gets displayed the way I want it to (so loading the main template and executing footer and header inside of it).

I couldn't find any documentation how to tell golang which template to use first. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Know that a [`template.Template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template) may be (usually is) a collection of multiple templates. The template contains a map of the associated templates. When using [`template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFiles) or [`template.ParseGlob()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseGlob), the returned `template.Template` will designate the first template that was parsed (from the multiple files). You can read more about this here: [Go template name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176355/go-template-name/41187671#41187671)

Instead of using [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) (which –based on the above– will execute the first parsed template) use the [`Template.ExecuteTemplate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ExecuteTemplate) method where you can specify which template you want to execute, specified by its name:

```
err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "main.html", data)
```

This will execute the template named `"main.html"` no matter in what order the template files were parsed (or later added to the template collection).