# Can't access data from html/template Golang

Tags: html, templates, go, go-templates

I have three concatenated templates. `base.html`, `menu.html`, `users.html`. But when I execute these templates I can access data of context only from `base.html`.

Here is my Handler:

```
func HandlerUser(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
if req.Method == "GET" {
    context := Context{Title: "Users"}
    users,err:= GetUser(0)
    context.Data=map[string]interface{}{
        "users": users,
    }
    fmt.Println(context.Data)
    t,err := template.ParseFiles("public/base.html")
    t,err = t.ParseFiles("public/menu.html")
    t,err = t.ParseFiles("public/users.html")
    err = t.Execute(res,context)
    fmt.Println(err)
 }
}
```

This is what I want to show in users template

```
{{ range $user := index .Data "users" }}
<tr id="user-{{ .Id }}">
    <td id="cellId" >{{ $user.Id }}</td>
    <td id="cellUserName" >{{ $user.UserName }}</td>
</tr>
{{ end }}
```

Note: I can access `"{{.Title}}"` that is used in `base.html` template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should check errors returned by the [`Template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ParseFiles) method. You store the returned error, but you only check it at the end (and by then it is overwritten like 3 times).

Next, never parse templates in the request handler, it's too time consuming and resource wasting. Do it once at startup (or on first demand). For details see [It takes too much time when using "template" package to generate a dynamic web page to client in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451675/it-takes-too-much-time-when-using-template-package-to-generate-a-dynamic-web-p/28453523#28453523).

Next, you can parse multiple files at once, just enumerate all when passing to the [`Template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ParseFiles) *function* (there is a method and a function).

Know that [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) only executes a single (named) template. You have 3 *associated* templates, but only the `"base.html"` template is executed by your code. To execute a specific, *named* template, use [`Template.ExecuteTemplate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ExecuteTemplate). For details, see [Telling Golang which template to execute first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605373/telling-golang-which-template-to-execute-first/42606082#42606082).

First you should define a *structure* of your templates, decide which templates include others, and execute the "wrapper" template (using `Template.ExecuteTemplate()`). When you execute a template that invokes / includes another template, you have the possibility to tell what value (data) you what to pass to its execution. When you write `{{template "something" .}}`, that means you want to pass the value currently pointed by dot to the execution of the template named `"something"`. Read more about this: [golang template engine pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507958/golang-template-engine-pipelines/42508255#42508255).

To learn more about template association and internals, read this answer: [Go template name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176355/go-template-name/41187671#41187671).

So in your case I would imagine that `"base.html"` is the wrapper, outer template, which includes `"menu.html"` and `"users.html"`. So `"base.html"` should contain lines similar to this:

```
{{template "menu.html" .}}

{{template "users.html" .}}
```

The above lines will invoke and include the results of the mentioned templates, passing the data to their execution that was passed to `"base.html"` (if dot was not changed).

Parse the files using the [`template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFiles) *function* (not method) like this:

```
var t *template.Template

func init() {
    var err error
    t, err = template.ParseFiles(
        "public/base.html", "public/menu.html", "public/users.html")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // handle error
    }
}
```

And execute it like this in your handler:

```
err := t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base.html", context)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I didnt put the dot pipeline to pass the Data