# Divide template to files error

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I’ve created a template which works as expected, now when the template is become bigger I want to
Divide it to several files, what I did is the following for example

**bigfile.txt :)**

```
echo “I’m pre process”

echo “process”

echo “I’m post process”




t := template.Must(template.New("bigfile.txt").Parse(bigfile.txt))
```

…

Now this is **working** without any problem.

What I did now is divide the big file to 3 files

```
**base_pre.txt**
```

And here is the code inside

```
{{define "base_pre”}}

echo “I’m pre process”

{{end}}
```

**base_pre.txt**

And here is the code inside

```
{{define "base_post”}}

echo “I’m post process”

{{end}}
```

And in the`bigfile.txt`I’ve changed the

```
{{template "base_pre"}}

echo process

{{template "base_post”}}
```

When I run it I got error

**ERROR** template: bigfile.txt:1:11: executing “bigfile.txt" at <{{template "base_pre...>: template "base_pre" not defined

Comment: First the last line in bigfile.txt should be {{template "base_post"}}, second: did you load the template files base_pre.txt and base_post.txt?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ParseFiles

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio - sorry i've fixed the typo, it's `template` as you mention (same error exist... how should I load them ? i've a place `template.New("bigfile.txt")` to load only one template ...

Comment: Sorry no time to answer right now, please refer to https://hackernoon.com/golang-template-2-template-composition-and-how-to-organize-template-files-4cb40bcdf8f6 to have some info

Comment: See an example of this here: [The Go Template ParseFiles func parsing multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979276/the-go-template-parsefiles-func-parsing-multiple-files/44979550#44979550).