# Golang template function returns blank page

Tags: go, go-templates

I am trying to change the default delimiters for Golang hml templates and here is the code I am using now:

```
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  pageFile := "html/testpage.html"
  tmpl, err := template.New(pageFile).Delims("[[", "]]").ParseFiles(pageFile)
  //tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(pageFile))
  if (err!=nil){
    fmt.Println("Error")
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

The above code renders a blank page in the browser. It will render properly if I use the commented out code instead of the second line.

Here is the template page source:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 </title>
  <meta name="description" content="HTML5">
  <meta name="author" content="Test">   
</head>    
<body>
  This is html page
</body>
</html>
```

My go version is: `go version go1.10.2 linux/amd64`

I run it by `go run test.go` test.go being in the main package

There is no error message being printed in the browser or the terminal.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `html/template` uses `text/template` underneath, you can often find additional information regarding how templates work in the `text/template` package.

From the docs of [ParseFiles](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.ParseFiles):

> Since the templates created by ParseFiles are named by the **base names**
>   of the argument files, t should *usually have the name* of one of the
>   (base) names of the files. If it does not, depending on t's contents
>   before calling ParseFiles, t.Execute **may fail**. In that case use
>   t.ExecuteTemplate to execute a valid template.

(emphasis mine)

---

The problem is caused by the fact that you are passing the template file's path as the name of the template and then calling the `ParseFiles` method.

Because of how [`ParseFiles`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ParseFiles), and [`ParseGlob`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ParseGlob) for that matter, are implemented, this causes an inconsistency between the name you explicitly passed to `New` and the names these two methods assign to the parsed templates.

You can test this by calling the [`DefinedTemplates`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.DefinedTemplates) method.

https://play.golang.org/p/LEi-xSn4LOF

---

Also please take a look at @icza's [Go template name answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176355/go-template-name/41187671#41187671) to get a better understanding of templates.

Comment: finally I could reproduce the OP problem, please see; https://play.golang.org/p/DOBzNqEdBjc

Comment: my example "doesn't work", it shows that when you use the path as the name and then call ParseFiles you'll get an inconsistency between the name of the template `t` and the name of the actual parsed template. `path+ParseFiles => name is: /tmp/054003078 ; defined templates are: "054003078"` this is not an ok output.

Comment: your example was incomplete... i just complete it in order to get the OP error... thanks ;)

Comment: consider adding the example that actually PRINTS an error, just a suggestion.. it helps me.

Comment: If all you want is to reproduce that specific error you can do this: `template.New("whatever").Execute(os.Stdout, nil)`.

Comment: not that @mkproiva i guess you are not getting into what i'm trying to find is the *root* of the problem. If you refer to the file using a path that includes "/" for the name of the template you get the problem. Instead if you only use the base name you won't, because there is no "/" in the path.

Comment: what happens if the use employs pageFile := "testpage.html", that would work? (assuming that the file is at that location at runtime)

Comment: That would work because the filepath and base name are the same. But passing "tmp/testpage.html" (without the leading "/") is not the base name of the file and therefore **may** fail.

Comment: so please, try to bear with me and don't deny that "/" is part of the problem.

Comment: you have said that... if you employ an "/" you get the problem, if you don't employ you don't... so.. i'm not saying THAT is the problem... i'm saying that is important part of the problem.

Comment: How is it part of the problem? If "tmp/testpage.html" and "/tmp/testpage.thml" both fail equally, how is "/" the problem here? Please elaborate @VIctor.

Comment: our discussion would be nice to have with a coffe dear mkpriva. I have plenty of stuff to learn for today. LEt's continue this another day, shall we?

Comment: To be clear "/" is not important, it is actually irrelevant, and you should not focus on that. You should think about the cause of the problem in terms of filepaths and base names.

Comment: well for a start i would argue that using template.NEw() followed by template.ParseFiles() does have any meaning? why not use directly template.ParseFiles()? I guess that open the way to discussion like the one we are having. See the snippet https://play.golang.org/p/408hyExUQ9k

Comment: and yes mkvpriva, by using "/" you are introducing an error to the ill way of using template. Ill way = `Template.NEw("blabla").ParseFiles(files)`

Comment: coffe with sugar?

Answer (score 4):

After some research and discussions i guess this line is ill formed:

```
tmpl, err := template.New(pageFile).ParseFiles(pageFile)
```

You don't need to do a `New(pageFile)`. You only need to use the `ParseFiles` method directly and bear in mind that the name of the templaes will be equals to the base names of the passed files.

So, touch a little bit yhe code and use:

```
tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(pageFile)
```

See [this example](https://go.dev/play/p/MFB5j2q6sBg) for more

Answer (score 0):

```
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  pageFile := "html/testpage.html"
  name := "testpage"
  tmpl, err := template.New(name).Delims("[[", "]]").ParseFiles(pageFile)  //only translate a "name" to New()
  //tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(pageFile))
  if (err!=nil){
    fmt.Println("Error")
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
  //tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, nil)
}
```