# Golang, template is undefined

Tags: go

I'm currently trying to create a small web application using golang and I'm following the tutorial on their webpage (https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/final.go). Instead of having the templates on the same folder as the rest of the code I'm trying to move them into `templates/template_name.html`.

For template rendering I'm using the following code:

```
var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/edit.html", "templates/view.html"))

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, p *Page) {
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "templates/"+tmpl+".html", p)
    if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

And for example my View handler is the following:

```
func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, title string) {                                                                                                                                    
    p, err := loadPage(title)                                                                                                                                                                           
    if err != nil {                                                                                                                                                                                     
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/edit/"+title, http.StatusFound)                                                                                                                                       
            return                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    renderTemplate(w, "view", p)                                                                                                                                                                        

}
```

I have the `templates/` folder with the `edit.html` and `view.html` file inside. I run the full code with: `go run wiki.go` but when I try to access the webpage I get the following error:

```
html/template: "templates/view.html" is undefined
```

Any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Read the documentation of ParseFiles. The name of the template is _not_ the filepath. So fix `"templates/"+tmpl+".html"`

Comment: I've read the documentation, but I don't understand how it can reach the template inside the folder without indicating it. I'm a little bit lost.

Comment: As @Volker wrote, the template name is just `"view.html"`, and not `"templates/view.html"`. Please see related / possible duplicate: [Go template name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176355/go-template-name/41187671#41187671).

Comment: Did you try a simple "edit.html"?

Comment: I just tried a simple edit.html and I still get the same error which is strange because I don't have '/templates' on any part of the code but it still references it.

Comment: make sure you save the code, run `go clean`, re-build the code and run it.

Comment: It's working now, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Like @Volker said, we use the template's path in `ParseFiles` and the filename in `ExecuteTemplate`:

```golang
var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/edit.html", "templates/view.html"))

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, p *Page) {
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl+".html", p)
    if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

My implementation: https://github.com/librity/gowiki