# html/template: "xxx" is undefined error for one page but not the other

Tags: html, go

again I'm stuck. I've been experimenting with Golang using this [page](http://sanatgersappa.blogspot.com/2013/11/creating-master-page-for-your-go-web-app.html) as a guide for templates to create a master page. I've managed to get the Go server up with my CSS and JS directories all updated correctly but I am only able to load the `index.html` page and not the `about.html` page. [Github link here](https://github.com/jzng89/TLDR-GO)

I have already tried the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500451/golang-template-is-undefined) and [here](https://github.com/kataras/iris/issues/485) but no luck, both the about page and index page are in the same directory and share the same header, footer and navigation bar templates.

I have also tried parsing files manually with `template.Must(template.ParseFiles("header.html", .....` and also tried executing with the .html in the name `templ.ExecuteTemplate(w, "about.html", &Page{Title: "About TL;DR"})` which does not return an error but instead just loads a blank screen. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

File directory:

[image: File directory structure]

servermain.go

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "html/template"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "os"
        "path/filepath"
        "strings"
    )

    //Page title
    type Page struct {
        Title string
    }

    //------------------------------Global Variables-------------------------------------//
    //Compile templates on start
    var templ = ParseTemplates()

    //ParseTemplates use for multi directory html parsing
    func ParseTemplates() *template.Template {
        t := template.New("Base")
        err := filepath.Walk("./", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
            if strings.Contains(path, ".html") {
                _, err = t.ParseFiles(path)
                fmt.Println(path)
                if err != nil {
                    logger.Println(err)
                    fmt.Println(err)
                }
            }

            return err
        })

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        return t
    }

    //logging
    var errorlog *os.File
    var logger *log.Logger

    //---------------------------------------Page Handlers----------------------------------//
    //Handler for homepage
    func homepageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Home")
        err := templ.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", &Page{Title: "Welcome to TL;DR"})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            logger.Println(err)
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    }

    //Handler for about page
    func aboutHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("About")
        err := templ.ExecuteTemplate(w, "about", &Page{Title: "About TL;DR"})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            logger.Println(err)
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    }

    //Server log to file
    func init() {
        errorlog, err := os.OpenFile("serverlog.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error opening file: %v", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        log.SetOutput(errorlog)
        logger = log.New(errorlog, "\r\nTDLR : ", log.Lshortfile|log.LstdFlags)
    }

    func main() {
        //--------------------------------------Routers-------------------------------------//
        http.HandleFunc("/", homepageHandler)
        http.HandleFunc("/index", homepageHandler)
        http.HandleFunc("/about", aboutHandler)

        http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
        //start server
        fmt.Println("Starting server on port 9090")
        logger.Println("Starting server on port 9090")
        logger.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil))

    }
```

Error page

[image: Error page]

Also I noticed no matter what page I load it will always execute the `homepageHandler` after executing the `aboutHandler` as can be seen in the console.

[image: Console result]

**Edit:** Solved 20181215
Improper definition of the `about.html` template, change to `{{define "about"}}` solved the problem.

Comment: Show us your `about.html`.

Comment: https://github.com/jzng89/TLDR-GO/blob/master/about.html#L1 You have to decide which is it, about or index? None of your template files defines an "about" template, no matter their filenames.

Comment: @mkopriva OMG thank you for pointing that out! I did not notice that I did not change the {{define ""}} parameter in the template when I was converting the the files into Go template formats. Can't believe after 6 hours of troubleshooting I did not notice that.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in my PC, it works OK.
If you see a blank screen with about.html ( .html in the name ) it's probably your template's problem.
Make sure you have below code inside your about.html

```
{{.Title}}
```