# Golang template order

Tags: go, go-templates

Is there a way to make the template order irrelevant.

Here's my code:

```
var overallTemplates = []string{
    "templates/analytics.html",
    "templates/header.html",
    "templates/footer.html"}

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    render(w,
        append([]string{"templates/home.html"}, overallTemplates...),
        nil)
}

func render(w http.ResponseWriter, files []string, data interface{}) {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(files...))
    err := tmpl.Execute(w, data)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Couldn't load template: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

It works but if I change the order of `overallTemplates` to:

```
var overallTemplates = []string{
    "templates/header.html",
    "templates/footer.html",
    "templates/analytics.html"}
```

I get a blank page because analytics.html content is something like `{{define "analytics"}}...{{end}}` and it's called by `footer.html` like `{{define "footer"}}{{template "analytics"}} ...{{end}}`

Comment: The order is already more or less irrelevant, what's relevant is which template you *execute*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFiles) documents that:

> The returned template's name will have the (base) name and (parsed) contents of the **first file**.

So in your first example your template designates `"templates/analytics.html"` because that's the first template you pass, and when you change order, the template will designate `"templates/header.html"`.

And if you execute the template with [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute), these are the (default) templates to be executed.

Instead you should use [`Template.ExecuteTemplate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ExecuteTemplate) and explicitly specify you want to execute the `"templates/analytics.html"`, whose name will be `analytics`, so pass that:

```
err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "analytics", data)
```

That way it will not matter in what order you pass the templates to `template.ParseFiles()`.

And a friendly note: do not parse your templates in the handler: it's slow. Parse them once, on app startup, store them e.g. in package variables, and just execute them in the handler. For details, see [It takes too much time when using "template" package to generate a dynamic web page to client in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451675/it-takes-too-much-time-when-using-template-package-to-generate-a-dynamic-web-p/28453523#28453523).

Also see related quesetion: [Go template name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176355/go-template-name/41187671#41187671)

Comment: I am newbie in Go so thanks so much for the additional note - very helpful.