# Why when I ignore the template.New() the program can run successfully?

Tags: go, templates, go-templates

I am trying to use `html/template` to parse a JSON in struct format.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var issueList = template.Must(template.New("template01").ParseFiles("template01.tmpl"))
    result, err := SearchIssues(os.Args[1:])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := issueList.Execute(w, result); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

The function `SearchIssues` is used to convert the stream into JSON format, it works well.

Then I try to parse the JSON by `html/template` using

```
var issueList = template.Must(template.New("template01").ParseFiles("template01.tmpl"))
```

When I access local services, there is an error : `XXX is an incomplete or empty template`.

But when I delete `New("template01").` the program runs well.

Like this:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var issueList = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("template01.tmpl"))
    result, err := SearchIssues(os.Args[1:])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := issueList.Execute(w, result); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I am not native speaker, English is not very well, sorry.

Comment: Why would you write `template.New("foo").ParseFiles()`? You'd use `template.New()` if you have a string constant that is to be used as a template, like `template.New("foo").Parse("<h1>{{ Title }}</h1><p>{{ Paragraph }}</p>")` or something along those lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your first code is that when you do:

```
var issueList = template.Must(template.New("template01").
    ParseFiles("template01.tmpl"))
```

[`template.New()`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#New) will create a new template having the name `"template01"`. The variable `issueList` will refer to this empty template. You call its [`Template.ParseFiles()`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.ParseFiles) **method**, which will parse the `"template01.tmpl"` file and create an *associated* template named `"template01.tmpl"`. The variable `issueList` will still refer to the `template01` template, not the one parsed from the file. When you call [`Template.Excute()`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.Execute), it executes the (default) template `issueList` designates, which is the empty `template01`. That's why you get the error `incomplete or empty template`.

In your second version:

```
var issueList = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("template01.tmpl"))
```

You call the [`template.ParseFiles()`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#ParseFiles) *function*, which parses the `"template01.tmpl"` file, and returns its template. So `issueList` will refer to the parsed template from the file, and not an empty template. So `Template.Execute()` will execute this template.

Note: if in the first case you'd use [`Template.ExecuteTemplate()`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.ExecuteTemplate), you can name the template you want to execute:

```
if err := issueList.Execute(w, "template01.tmpl", result); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

This will succeed because you tell explicitly to execute the `"template01.tmpl"` parsed from the file, and not the default, empty template.

Also note that you should not parse the templates in your handler, it's slow. Parse it before that once, store the result in package level variables and just execute it in the handler. For dteails, see [It takes too much time when using "template" package to generate a dynamic web page to client in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451675/it-takes-too-much-time-when-using-template-package-to-generate-a-dynamic-web-p/28453523#28453523)

For details about associated templates, see [Go template name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176355/go-template-name/41187671#41187671).

Also please use [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) to generate JSON output and not `text/template` or `html/template`. The template engine knows nothing about JSON format and encoding, and may easily generate invalid JSON.

Comment: additional, you suggestion me use the encoding/json to prase JSON-type string. if i want to use some members to generate the HTML page, i should use the encoding/json first, then add the result to the HTML page by using JSP. It seems like more complicated, but safe. that is your meaning right? but the template's function is unemployed. i want to ask which occasion template is used normally?

Comment: To generate or parse JSON, use `encoding/json`. If you want to embed the JSON text in an HTML page, then use `html/template`.